# Jquery Dialog Positioning in Firefox on second click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have implemented jquery dialog with iFrame and I am passing URL of my page to that dialog iframe to open that page in jquery dialog.

It works fine in IE and Firefox but - In Firefox
If we open dialog on first click it opens properly in center but on second click and if we have contents on page with scroll then it looks for center position and show little down on page from cursor.

Please help.

Comment: @Niklas it's .net :x http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and it turned out that was because i didn't set up the height of the dialogue.